# Capture one line of Serial Data from SerialPort Class

Tags: c#

I have a serial connection that gives me multiple lines of text continuously.  I just want to capture one of those lines using the SerialPort method in C#.  How would I go about capturing just one line of the output from the Serial Port?  I know all of the COM port/baud rate/bit rate/parity settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SerialPort.ReadLine().  Tweak the NewLine and the Encoding property if neccessary.